# Windows .net Google.Apis hangs on the call to InsertMediaUpload.Upload -- there is no timeout

Tags: google-drive-api, google-docs, google-docs-api

I am using GoogleApis to upload documents to Google Drive using the InsertMediaUpload class from the FilesResource namespace and the Upload method. It is working well for me with the following exception:

After calling InsertMediaUpload, a browser window appears asking the user to log into their Google (usually Gmail) account. If the user simply closes the browser window instead of clicking on "Accept" or "Cancel" then the current process appears to be hung. I suppose there should a timeout of a minute or two so that if the user opts to not log in the current windows application will not simply hang and stop working indefinitely.

There is no need for sample code here. What should happen when the user simply closes the browser window instead of clicking cancel if they are no longer interested in uploading a document? Crashing (or hanging) the current process should not be a possibility, but that is what occurs. One would hope closing the browser window would have the same effect as clicking the cancel button -- just another way of opting out of an upload to Google Drive, right?

Thanks in advance for any help with this.

Answer (score 1):

You're not supposed to get authentication message from InsertMediaUpload class. You should handle authentication by yourself. Authentication browser window you get is for your development convenience, not for production code. Please take a look at [.net quickstart](https://developers.google.com/drive/quickstart-cs). In this quickstart, you'll see `GetAuthorization` method which handles authentication. Modify this method on your needs and you'll get what you want.

Comment: I don't have the code with me right now to examine, but at some point a browser window appears asking the user to log in to their Google Drive using their user name and password. The user is given the choices "Allow" or "Cancel", but a third option is to simply close the browser window altogether. Now this should have the same effect as clicking the Cancel button, but instead it hangs the current process. When I wrote the message above I thought this occurred when the Upload method of the InsertMediaUpload class is called, but perhaps a delgate was passed to Upload for Authentication purposes.

Comment: Okay, let me explain why that is happening. You are probably using local webserver authentication module of google api client. This program sets up a webserver and waits until oauth2callback is triggered. That is why it stalls forever when user closes window without accepting or canceling. Again, this is not production code and everything is working as intended. You should handle authentication yourself to prevent this.

Comment: I believe the authentication browser window is required because my application does not and should not know anything about the user credentials to access Google Drive. My application simply receives the authorization token which is created for me as follows:

Comment: 1) My CreateAuthenticator method has this code:
private static IAuthenticator CreateAuthenticator()
{
 var provider = new NativeApplicationClient(GoogleAuthenticationServer.Description);
 provider.ClientIdentifier = CLIENT_ID;
 provider.ClientSecret = GetClientSecret();
 return new OAuth2Authenticator<NativeApplicationClient>(provider, GetAuthorization);
}

Comment: 2) My GetAuthorization checks to see if an authorization token has been provided previously for reuse. If not then it calls AuthorizationMgr.RequestNativeAuthorization, passing as parameters the NativeApplicationClient and the scopes string array containing this single string: "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file"

Comment: 3) AuthorizationMgr.RequestNativeAuthorization calls an overloaded method with the same name, which calls LoopbackServerAuthoirzationFlow.RetrieveAuthorization.

Comment: 4) LoopbackServerAuthoirzationFlow.RetrieveAuthorization creates a local url with this format: "http://localhost:{0}/{1}/authorize/" with parmeter 0 set local unused port and parameter 1 set to the name of the current application. This local url is then added to a newly created HttpListener.

Comment: 5) The authorizationState.Callback property is set to a new URI with the local url, and a google authorization url is obtained with this call: Uri authUrl = client.RequestUserAuthorization(authorizationState);

Comment: 6) A browser instance is created using Process.Start and passing in the authUrl from step 5.